# Unary operator minus (-) cannot be applied to type uint256

Tags: solidity, uniswap, solidity-0.7.x, solidity-0.8.x

While trying to compile the [mulDiv](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/f03155670ec1667406b83a539e23dcccf32a03bc/contracts/libraries/FullMath.sol#L14-L106) function part of the [uniswap-v3-core](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core) code base, I got the following error:

> Unary operator - cannot be applied to type uint256

This is the line that causes the compile error:

```
uint256 twos = -denominator & denominator;
```

I'm using using Solidity v0.8.3, while they [used](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/f03155670ec1667406b83a539e23dcccf32a03bc/hardhat.config.ts#L12) Solidity v0.7.6.

This doesn't seem to be listed in the [v0.8.0 breaking changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html). How can I make it work in v0.8 while ensuring that the logic stays the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The unary operator `-` negates the given number. It is easier to see what it does with signed integers. If we use the `int8` type and we negate the positive number 10, we get -10 back.

Now, unsigned integers can't represent negative numbers, of course. What Solidity does when negating an uint8 `x` (in v0.7 and below) is to return `type(uint8).max - x + 1`. For example, negating 10 gives us 246.

The following function that I wrote returns `true` for all possible values of `x`:

```
function checkNegativeUnary(uint8 x) external pure returns (bool result) {
    uint8 a = -x;
    uint8 b = type(uint8).max - x + 1;
    result = a == b;
}
```

Since it seems like Solidity v0.8 forbids the negation of unsigned integers now, to make the `mulDiv` compile we should rewrite that `denominator` like this:

```
uint256 twos = (type(uint256).max - denominator + 1) & denominator;
```

This doesn't overflow because `denominator` can never be 0, due to another check made earlier in the function:

```
// Make sure the result is less than 2**256.
// Also prevents denominator == 0
require(denominator > prod1);
```

### Update

I managed to find a shorter implementation, as per the answers in this Q&A I started in the CS SE: [How to find the largest power of two divisor of a given integer?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138556/how-to-find-the-largest-power-of-two-divisor-of-a-given-integer):

```
uint256 twos = denominator & (~denominator + 1);
```

Note that this is faster than the other solution *only* if you're using [checked arithmetic](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic).

Comment: do you have any idea how this line could be modified to work with Solidity version 0.8? https://github.com/pooltogether/uniform-random-number/blob/master/contracts/UniformRandomNumber.sol#L33

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head. Tinker with the `&` operator on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) until you find the solution. Or open another question on StackExchange.