# "bitwise and" operation between value and its two's component

Tags: solidity, uniswap, math

this operation `uint256 pow2 = d & -d` is from [FullMath.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/solidity-lib/blob/master/contracts/libraries/FullMath.sol)

```
 function fullDiv(
        uint256 l,
        uint256 h,
        uint256 d
    ) private pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 pow2 = d & -d;   
        d /= pow2;      
        .....
    }
```

I tested this operation with 20 and -20.

```
    00010100 = 20
    11101100 = -20
```

its bitwise and result is (If I am not mistaken so far)

```
 00010100 & 11101100=00000100
```

Why is this significant? Uniswap named variable AS `pow2` but all the numbers from binary are already the power of 2. After the bitwise operation, `d` is divided by `pow2=d & -d`. I am trying to understand, what is the point of this division.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unary operator minus (-) cannot be applied to type uint256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96642/unary-operator-minus-cannot-be-applied-to-type-uint256)

Comment: @Yilmaz What's the question?

Comment: @Ismael what is the importance of `d /= pow2` How do we interpret its result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the importance of d /= pow2

The calculation `uint256 pow2 = d & -d` is the greatest power of 2 that divides `d`.

With `d /= pow2` it is removing the zeros to the right. It is the "shifting" to the right both numerator and denominator. For example 51 / 20 = (51 / 4) / (20 / 4) = 12.75 / 5.

It is an optimization.